# Review of a rocket flight controller schematic

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, esp32, usb-c

I am currently designing a model rocket flight controller, which is supposed to calculate the altitude using a barometer and accelerometer and fire two pyro channels for two stage parachute ejection. It also has the ability to control three servos. The microcontroller is a ESP32-S3_WROOM. I power everything with a 2S (7.4 - 8.4V) LiPo battery. As I am still new to PCB and schematic design, I would appreciate if someone could point out any mistakes I made. This is the schematic: [image]